# Parsing WMS-name from logfile i python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm quiet new to python and I'm tring to (using python) go through a number of large custom log files to extract parameters from certain GET-requests an try to gain som statistics from them. I got kinda far but i got stuck with two questions that me and my collegue couldnt figure out why they are giving us such headache.

```
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:25 860" "POST /bios/servlet/bios.servlets.sso.WaffleLoginServlet HTTP/1.1" 401 5 891 891 "-" "Java/1.8.0_171"
8080 172.23.131.251 "2018-07-05 13:08:26 594" "HEAD /bios/servlet/bios.servlets.web.Ping?level=3 HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1953 1953 "-" "-"
8080 172.23.131.252 "2018-07-05 13:08:26 594" "HEAD /bios/servlet
bios.servlets.web.Ping?level=3 HTTP/1.0" 200 - 953 953 "-" "-"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 188" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_HYBRID_INTERN?TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=p_1002095&SRS=EPSG%3A3011&STYLES=&r=n2q&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=156240.234375%2C6576777.34375%2C156269.53125%2C6576806.640625 HTTP/1.1" 200 133210 3547 3516 "http://tkkarta3.stockholm.se/astolmap/v3/kopplet/tkkarta.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 188" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_HYBRID_INTERN?TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=p_1002095&SRS=EPSG%3A3011&STYLES=&r=n2q&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=156240.234375%2C6576748.046875%2C156269.53125%2C6576777.34375 HTTP/1.1" 200 108066 3547 3532 "http://tkkarta3.stockholm.se/astolmap/v3/kopplet/tkkarta.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 188" "POST /bios/servlet/bios.servlets.GetGeometryComponents HTTP/1.1" 401 4 2484 2484 "-" "Java/1.8.0_171"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 204" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_HYBRID_INTERN?TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=p_1002095&SRS=EPSG%3A3011&STYLES=&r=n2q&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=156210.9375%2C6576806.640625%2C156240.234375%2C6576835.9375 HTTP/1.1" 200 123953 3563 3547 "http://tkkarta3.stockholm.se/astolmap/v3/kopplet/tkkarta.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 204" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_HYBRID_INTERN?TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=p_1002095&SRS=EPSG%3A3011&STYLES=&r=n2q&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=156210.9375%2C6576777.34375%2C156240.234375%2C6576806.640625 HTTP/1.1" 200 147132 3563 3547 "http://tkkarta3.stockholm.se/astolmap/v3/kopplet/tkkarta.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.131.149 "2018-07-05 13:08:28 204" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_HYBRID_INTERN?TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=p_1002095&SRS=EPSG%3A3011&STYLES=&r=n2q&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=156269.53125%2C6576777.34375%2C156298.828125%2C6576806.640625 HTTP/1.1" 200 145701 3563 3547 "http://tkkarta3.stockholm.se/astolmap/v3/kopplet/tkkarta.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.137.120 "2018-07-06 10:04:32 856" "GET /bios/wms/app/baggis/web/WMS_STHLM_STOCKHOLMSKARTA_GRA?FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TILED=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A5850&BBOX=150000,6580000,151875,6581875&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256 HTTP/1.1" 200 58443 0 0 "https://iservice.stockholm.se/open/TyckTill/Pages/TyckTill.aspx?systemId=synpunktsportalen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
80 172.23.137.120 "2018-07-06 10:04:25 400" "GET /bios/dpwebmap/cust_sth/slk/tycktill/app.htmlclient.gwt.DPWebApp.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3924 0 0 "https://iservice.stockholm.se/open/TyckTill/Pages/TyckTill.aspx?systemId=synpunktsportalen" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
```

***What i try to do***

1. Extracting the name of the service for all lines with a string "REQUEST=GetMap". The name of the service is between the string "/bios/wms/app/" and the FIRST questionsmark "?" in the line. I mention that it has to be the first questionsmark because there can be several questionsmarks in each line (eg the second last line in my log example has two questionmarks).

The regex i use is:

```
rexp_name = r"(^.+/bios/wms/app/(?P<name>.+)\?)"
```

My problem is that my regex just finds the last questionmark in the line and returns the whole string between "/bios/wms/app/" and the last questionsmark instead of just the first one. The name gets to long for the lines with several questionmarks.

***Do you have any ideas how to accomplish that the regex stops after the first questionsmark?***

Comment: try this pattern: `rexp_name = r"(^.+/bios/wms/app/(?P<name>.+?)\?)"`. The extra question mark makes the + non greedy.

Comment: Alternative you can also negate the character like in `rexp_name = r"(^.+/bios/wms/app/(?P<name>[^?]+)\?)"`

Comment: Of course!! Thank you @nauer! The regex rexp_name = r"(^.+/bios/wms/app/(?P<name>.+?)\?)" does the trick. A little bit confusing to have question marks in the string and question marks in the code. :D